# Can't build docker image via gradle on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, docker, gradle

I am new to Docker and i have problems with building image from the gradle script using [gradle-docker-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) :

```
task dockerBuildImage(type: DockerBuildImage, dependsOn: [dockerCreateDockerfile, assemble]) {
    tag = "my_tag_here"
    dockerFile = dockerCreateDockerfile.destFile
    inputDir = dockerCreateDockerfile.destFile.parentFile
}
```

And than i am getting such stacktrace:

```
Building image using context 'D:\Learning\1\myproject\webapp\build'.
Using Dockerfile 'D:\Learning\1\myproject\webapp\build\Dockerfile'
Using tag 'localhost:5000/test/myproject-webapp:1.0.0-20170318135307' for image.
Operating System not officially supported by junixsocket: Windows 10
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find library in classpath, tried: [libjunixsocket-windows10-1.8-amd64.so, libjunixsocket-windows10-1.5-amd64.so]
        at org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket.load(NativeUnixSocket.java:81)
        at org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket.<clinit>(NativeUnixSocket.java:112)
        at org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocket.<init>(AFUNIXSocket.java:36)
        at org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocket.newInstance(AFUNIXSocket.java:50)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.ApacheUnixSocket.<init>(ApacheUnixSocket.java:51)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.UnixConnectionSocketFactory.createSocket(UnixConnectionSocketFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.POSTCallbackNotifier.response(POSTCallbackNotifier.java:29)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:50)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[dockerjava-jaxrs-async-0] ERROR com.github.dockerjava.core.async.ResultCallbackTemplate - Error during callback
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket
        at org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketImpl.connect(AFUNIXSocketImpl.java:134)
        at org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocket.connect(AFUNIXSocket.java:97)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.ApacheUnixSocket.connect(ApacheUnixSocket.java:62)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.UnixConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(UnixConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.POSTCallbackNotifier.response(POSTCallbackNotifier.java:29)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:50)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:webapp:dockerBuildImage FAILED
```

If i run "docker build" command directly - everything working fine. 
Can someone point me direction what can be wrong. Any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin doesn't support Windows. It assumes you are running on a Linux system, because that's what Docker Engine requires. Docker for Windows uses Hyper-V virtualization (previously it relied on VirtualBox).

You'll need to run this Gradle plugin on a Linux system. That could be a VM on your Windows machine. I prefer to skip Docker for Windows; instead I run VirtualBox with a suitable Linux guest, then follow the installation instructions for Docker Engine inside that guest. Then, alongside `docker` in that guest, you can install `gradle` and any other development tools you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're running an old version of junixsocket that does not support Windows. You need to upgrade to a later version.

Try changing your junixsocket dependencies to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.kohlschutter.junixsocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>junixsocket-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

PS: You have another error in the dependency configuration for native-common: `<type>pom</type>` should only be specified for `junixsocket-core`, which is a POM-type artifact that includes `junixsocket-common` and `junixsocket-native-common`, which are both jar-type artifacts. Therefore just remove that declaration, since `junixsocket-core` is all you should need.